# What does $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] do?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm unable to understand how $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] works. From where does this get value of 'redirect_to'?

```
 public function render_login_form( $attributes, $content = null ) {
    // Parse shortcode attributes
    $default_attributes = array( 'show_title' => false );
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );
    $show_title = $attributes['show_title'];

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return __( 'You are already signed in.', 'personalize-login' );
    }

    // Pass the redirect parameter to the WordPress login functionality: by default,
    // don't specify a redirect, but if a valid redirect URL has been passed as
    // request parameter, use it.
    $attributes['redirect'] = '';
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $attributes['redirect'] = wp_validate_redirect( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'], $attributes['redirect'] );
    }

    // Render the login form using an external template
    return $this->get_template_html( 'login_form', $attributes );
```

Comment: May either be from the GET or the POST request..

an example of the redirect_to in URL is when you go to the admin panel using the URL -> http://yoursite.com/wp-admin

Comment: You can read about $_REQUEST here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 4):

Here, $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] is default parameter available in WordPress to redirect once you login correctly while sign in or sign up. e.g. User Dashboard. Ref : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

In General redirect_to will redirect user to user dashboard or same page if any credential or details false.